# How to get the attributes from a node xml

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

is something like node.Attributes["name"].InnerText the good way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xattribute.value.aspx) property of the [XAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xattribute.aspx) class:

```
string attrValue = element.Attribute("name").Value;
```

Note that the [Attributes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341024.aspx) method returns an [`IEnumerable<XAttribute>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) that you have to iterate over, instead of an `XAttribute` instance. Moreover, those are methods and not indexed properties: you need to call them using parenthesis and not square brackets.

`XAttribute` also doesn't support an `InnerText` property, so you'll have to use `Value` instead.

Comment: whats the difference? Also, what's the difference between Attributes[xxx] and Attribute(xxx)?

Comment: @user496949, there's no difference because `XAttribute` does not support `InnerText`. See my updated answer. I used LINQ To XML types since your question is tagged as such, maybe you wanted something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this option, to catch an exception if the attribute is null

```
string attrValue = node.Attributes["name"] == null ? string.Empty : node.Attributes["name"].Value;
```